# How to set CodeIgniter to ignore blog folder

Tags: codeigniter

I have my site built on codeigniter e.g www.example.com and blog www.example.com/blog on wordpress
My HtAccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

How do i tell codeigniter to ignore the folder blog

Comment: RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]

Comment: After `RewriteEngine On` add `RewriteCond $1 ^(blog)`.